# mmap(MAP_SHARED) call not working in GPFS

Tags: c, linux, mmap

I am having problems with files that were modified with mmap(MAP_SHARED) in GPFS file system. Here is what I am doing:

```
#define SZ 10
int fd = open("out", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0660);
ftruncate(fd, SZ);
void *buf = mmap(0, SZ, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
*(int*)buf = 1;
msync(buf, SZ, MS_SYNC);
close(fd);
```

After that command `xxd ./out` shows 4096 zeroed bytes instead of 10 with leading 0x01. This code works well in ext fs. My GPFS version is 5.0.4 Am I doing smth wrong or it is issue in GPFS?

Comment: Difficult to answer your question as GPFS source code is apparently not available. According to this [page](https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00006LKv5B/mmap-performance-questions?language=en_US), "mmap and GPFS are not friends"

Comment: Yes, I have seen this discussion while I was searching the reason. But there is said only about performance, not conflict or issue in usage. Searching have not helped, I wonder that no one have faced with such issue

Comment: Is it a typo in your code snippet :  "void buf = mmap(0, SZ, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);" should be "void *buf...." ?

Comment: exactly:) made it during moving here

Comment: I think there should be an `munmap` call before `close`.

Comment: @mch : we can close the file descriptor of a "mmapped" file. As long as it is "mmaped", we can use the memory segment to update it. But you are right : at one moment, munmap() and close() (in any order) should be called to terminate the operations on the file.

Comment: I have added 'munmap(buf, SZ)' before close. Unfortunately, nothing has changed